# Python import local package that is already installed

Tags: python, import, module, package

I have installed this python module https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot and now I downloaded the project to modify things locally. The problem is that when I execute an [example](https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/blob/master/examples/basic_example.py) of the `examples` folder, it still loads the installed package. I tried [Importing modules from parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder) but it says:

```
import os,sys,inspect 
currentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.curr‌​entframe()))) 
parentdir = os.path.dirname(currentdir) 
sys.path.insert(0,parentdir)    
import chatterbot
```

> Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import

I think it will only work for simple `.py` files, not an entire project. Tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11158224/5884503) from the same question and it worked but broke for all the other imports inside the project.

Shouldn't these examples be adapted to work locally already, as they're rapidly tested by the developer? How to import the package locally?

Comment: Please show your `import` statement.

Comment: @DYZ its this one https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/blob/master/examples/basic_example.py

Comment: Nope. _Your_ `import` statement - the one that actually causes the error.

Comment: @DYZ import os,sys,inspect
currentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
parentdir = os.path.dirname(currentdir)
sys.path.insert(0,parentdir) 

import chatterbot